# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{x-1}\frac{1}{x-n}$ has a limit as $x \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: summation

Consider the sum

$A = \frac{1}{x-1} + \frac{1}{x-2} + \ldots + 1 = \sum_{n=1}^{x-1}\frac{1}{x-n},\quad x > 2$

Can anyone provide some hints on how to proof that the $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}A$ exists or not? Initially I thought the sum goes to infinity as $x$ increases, but [plotting](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%28d%28sum%201%2F%28h-n%29%20n%3D1%20to%20%28h-1%29%29%2Fdh%29) $\frac{\partial{A}}{\partial{x}}$ shows that the rate of change of $A$ goes to zero as $x$ increases.

Comment: This is just the harmonic series.

Comment: Indeed, with a change of variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reindex as follows.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{x-1}\frac{1}{x-n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {1\over k}.$$
This is the harmonic series and it diverges.  In fact
$$\sum_{k=1}^n {1\over k} = \log(n) + O(1). $$

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is the harmonic series, which diverges due to the fact that we can rearrange it as $$1+\dfrac{1}{2}+(\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{4})+(\dfrac{1}{5}+\dfrac{1}{6}+\dfrac{1}{7}+\dfrac{1}{8})+\dots\gt 1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dots$$